# Jmeter Webdriver opening empty browsers

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

### I am newly starting JMeter Webdriver. I have downloaded all plugin from Jmeter and downloaded chrome driver and specified the path in jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config. I am just trying to open "http://jmeter-plugins.org" . But when i am executing only chrome browser launched with ":data". Chrome Version:Version 76.0.3809.132 Selenium/WebDriver Support : 3.1 Java Version : 1.8 Code: WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org') WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd() Logs: 2019-08-27 10:49:19,418 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 2019-08-27 10:49:19,418 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 2019-08-27 10:49:19,434 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*) 2019-08-27 10:49:19,449 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 2019-08-27 10:49:19,449 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 2019-08-27 10:49:19,449 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 2019-08-27 10:49:19,449 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false 2019-08-27 10:49:19,465 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 2019-08-27 10:49:19,465 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 2019-08-27 10:49:19,465 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2019-08-27 10:49:28,655 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Start: Stopping test 2019-08-27 10:49:28,671 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping: Thread Group 1-1 2019-08-27 10:49:32,694 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132) Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: '43601JNBPBB115L', ip: '10.19.137.150', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver remote stacktrace: Backtrace: Ordinal0 [0x00D27C53+1473619] Ordinal0 [0x00CAAD71+961905] Ordinal0 [0x00C342B3+475827] Ordinal0 [0x00C2C420+443424] Ordinal0 [0x00C2BA5C+440924] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5F4+439796] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5B5+439733] Ordinal0 [0x00C32B15+469781] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B56C+439660] Ordinal0 [0x00C2C0C5+442565] Ordinal0 [0x00C2BA5C+440924] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5F4+439796] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5B5+439733] Ordinal0 [0x00C3146E+463982] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B56C+439660] Ordinal0 [0x00C2C0C5+442565] Ordinal0 [0x00C2BA5C+440924] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5F4+439796] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5B5+439733] Ordinal0 [0x00C2FC6B+457835] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B56C+439660] Ordinal0 [0x00C2C0C5+442565] Ordinal0 [0x00C2BA5C+440924] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5F4+439796] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5B5+439733] Ordinal0 [0x00C2F457+455767] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B56C+439660] Ordinal0 [0x00C2C0C5+442565] Ordinal0 [0x00C2BA5C+440924] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5F4+439796] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B5B5+439733] Ordinal0 [0x00C2824C+426572] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B56C+439660] Ordinal0 [0x00C2B454+439380] Ordinal0 [0x00C34F10+478992] Ordinal0 [0x00BE98FE+170238] Ordinal0 [0x00BE8D1D+167197] Ordinal0 [0x00BE742B+160811] Ordinal0 [0x00BD0AE6+68326] Ordinal0 [0x00BD1BF0+72688] Ordinal0 [0x00BD1B89+72585] Ordinal0 [0x00CC4B37+1067831] GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC6845+506677] GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC65E0+506064] GetHandleVerifier [0x00DCD188+533624] GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC701A+508682] Ordinal0 [0x00CBC226+1032742] Ordinal0 [0x00CBC09F+1032351] Ordinal0 [0x00CC6A4B+1075787] Ordinal0 [0x00CC6BB3+1076147] Ordinal0 [0x00CC5B65+1071973] BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75E5EF3C+18] RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77D93618+239] RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77D935EB+194] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:74) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171] 2019-08-27 10:49:32,694 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 2019-08-27 10:49:32,694 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 2019-08-27 10:49:32,694 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

Comment: Hi @suruthi pay attention to question formatting, at this momento your questione is really difficult to read, try to editing the question, by formatting code (or logs) inside backtick (``` [code] ```) and the text not in bold (in markdown bold is the text inside asterisks ** [test] **).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to download [ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.126/) as this is the only version compatible with your Chrome version
2. Use clean installation of the [latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and add Selenium/WebDriver support plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/). You should have [selenium-support-3.14.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/3.14.0), not `3.1` in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and this way WebDriver Sampler plugin should work properly as it appears that you're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)